# How can i troubleshoot my code? It works fine for a few minutes and then crashes

Tags: python

i keep getting this after the code runs for a minute or so...

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "rapid7_helper.py", line
> 233, in 
> _request()   File "rapid7_helper.py", line 31, in _request
> resp = requests.post(url=url1, headers=headers, json=third_party_patching_filer, verify=False).json()   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 898,
> in json
> return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/simplejson/**init**.py", line
> 525, in loads
> return _default_decoder.decode(s)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line
> 370, in decode
> obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line
> 400, in raw_decode
> return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end()) simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1
> (char 0)

is it possible to assign two different variables for my resp2? I need to be able to filter out "tags" from my rapid7 api as well as getting the next Key

```
def _request():

    third_party_patching_filer = {
    "asset": "asset.agentKey IS NOT NULL", 
    "vulnerability" : "vulnerability.categories NOT IN ['microsoft patch']"}

    headers = _headers()
    print(headers)
    url1 = f"https://us.api.insight.rapid7.com/vm/v4/integration/assets"
    resp = requests.post(url=url1, headers=headers, json=third_party_patching_filer, verify=False).json()

    jsonData = resp
    #print(jsonData)

    has_next_cursor = False
    nextKey = ""
  
    if "cursor" in jsonData["metadata"]:
        has_next_cursor = True
        nextKey = jsonData["metadata"]["cursor"]

    while has_next_cursor:

        url2 = f"https://us.api.insight.rapid7.com/vm/v4/integration/assets?&size=10&cursor={nextKey}"
        resp2 = requests.post(url=url2, headers=headers, json=third_party_patching_filer, verify=False).json()
        #print(resp2)
        #totalResources = resp2["metadata"]["totalResources"]
        desktop_support = resp2['data']
        cursor = resp2["metadata"]

        if "cursor" in cursor:
            nextKey = cursor["cursor"]
            print(f"next key {nextKey}")
            #print(desktop_support)
            for data in desktop_support:
                for tags in data['tags']:

                    #print(f"Tags from response{tags}")

                    if tags["name"] == 'OSSWIN':
                        print("OSSWIN")
                        total_critical_vul_osswin = []
                        total_severe_vul_osswin = []
                        total_modoer_vuln_osswin = []
                        critical_vuln_osswin = data['critical_vulnerabilities']
                        severe_vuln_osswin = data['severe_vulnerabilities']
                        modoer_vuln_osswin = data['moderate_vulnerabilities']
                        total_critical_vul_osswin.append(critical_vuln_osswin)
                        total_severe_vul_osswin.append(severe_vuln_osswin)
                        total_modoer_vuln_osswin.append(modoer_vuln_osswin)

                        print(sum(total_critical_vul_osswin))
                        print(sum(total_severe_vul_osswin))
                        print(sum(total_modoer_vuln_osswin))

                    if tags["name"] == 'DESKTOP_SUPPORT':
                        print("Desktop")
                        total_critical_vul_desktop = []
                        total_severe_vul_desktop = []
                        total_modoer_vuln_desktop = []
                        critical_vuln_desktop = data['critical_vulnerabilities']
                        severe_vuln_desktop = data['severe_vulnerabilities']
                        modoer_vuln_desktop = data['moderate_vulnerabilities']
                        total_critical_vul_desktop.append(critical_vuln_desktop)
                        total_severe_vul_desktop.append(severe_vuln_desktop)
                        total_modoer_vuln_desktop.append(modoer_vuln_desktop)
                        print(sum(total_critical_vul_desktop))
                        print(sum(total_severe_vul_desktop))
                        print(sum(total_modoer_vuln_desktop))
                    else:
                        print("Nothing to do here...")
```

i believe the errors started when i started doing the more if's (last two), it wouldnt error out when i just get the next cursor.  Is there a better way i can turn my if tags["name"] == 'OSSWIN': into a function? im only 5-6 months or so into python, how can i troubleshoot my error?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the full error? From what you've shown it looks like you are tying to parse something as json that isn't json. You might want to add some checks to make sure that the response is json.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please add the full stack trace of the error you're getting to your question.  Are you running your code in a debugger and looking at what it's doing.  That's how to troubleshoot your error.

Answer (score 1):

That error means that your code expected JSON data but got something else. I would suggest adding `print(resp.text)` and `print(resp2.text)` underneath both of your requests so that you can see exactly what data you are getting back.

Comment: thanks! where can i put this? after my for data in desktop_support or before?

Comment: I printed it and it really doesnt tell me anything on how to fix it, is it ok that i assign my resp2 to two different variables? it just says it cant find 'data'

Comment: I would do this
```resp = requests.post(url=url1, headers=headers, json=third_party_patching_filer, verify=False)``` followed by the print statement on the next line ```print(resp.text)```
and verify that the response that you are getting back is indeed json. If not, if it's say text, it may provide some useful error data to help you figure out the next steps.

Comment: If you follow my troubleshooting step above then you will also need to change ```jsonData = resp``` to ```jsonData = resp.json()```.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, a JSON decode error means a status code !== 2xx. Check this before you convert to JSON like so:

```py
req = requests.post(url)
if req.status_code == 200: # can also use "req.ok" to see if it's 2xx
  req.json()
else:
  print(f"Debug! Status code was {req.status_code} with URL: {url}")
  # ...
```

Comment: thanks, i get AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'status_code'
when i add this in

Comment: If your request looks like `req=requests.post(url)`, you should be able to check the status code like described. See this documentation: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#json-response-content. Are you sure you didnt do `requests.post().json()`?